# Angular 2 list out checkboxes that need to be preticked and get those values on form submit

Tags: javascript, angular

I have a list of checkboxes that I need to render out via the items json array and pre-tick them should "item.isInPackage" be equal to true:

```
<tr *ngFor="let item of items"><td><input id="item.id" type="checkbox" [checked]="item.isInPackage"></td></tr>
```

On submit of the form, how can I produce a json object array similar to the below for the checkbox ids that were ticked:

```
[
  {
    "fixtureId": 1
  },
{
    "fixtureId": 2
  }
]
```

I'm confused as to whether the checkboxes also need [(ngModel)] applied to them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `[(ngModel)]` but you don't have to. I used `(click)` and bound it to a function that build the JSON. Here is what I did : **[Plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/W3TO2gYvQKaQyje94ALi?p=preview)**

```
@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  template: `
    <input *ngFor="let item of items" id="item?.fixture.id" type="checkbox" (click)="setObj(item)" [checked]="item.isInPackage" #item?.fixture.id>
  {{obj}}`,
  styles: []
})
export class FormComponent implements OnInit {

  items : any[] = [{fixtureId:1,isInPackage:false},{fixtureId:2,isInPackage: false}]
  obj : string = "[]";

  constructor(){

  }

  setObj(item){
    let obj = JSON.parse(this.obj);
    item.isInPackage = !item.isInPackage;
    if(!item.isInPackage){
      obj.forEach((e,i) => {
        e.fixtureId === item.fixtureId ? obj.splice(i,1) : null;
      })
    } else {
      obj.push({fixtureId:item.fixtureId});
    }
    this.obj = JSON.stringify(obj);
  }

}
```